# D3.js and nested data - Why is my exit() set empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

I'm having an issue when dealing with manipulating nested data with D3.js

Data consists of array of objects which represent `categories`.
Each category has multiple `checkin`s.
I want a section for every `category`, and within that, a div for each `checkin`. I manipulate data over time and rely on update, enter and exit mechanisms of D3.js to properly output the data to DOM.

What I don't understand:

- **Why when second update is invoked, the old data doesn't show up in the exit() set**, and therefore is not deleted?
- **Why when `update()` is invoked third time with `data1` again, entries are again appended again despite the key function in data being provided**? By my understanding at this point D3 should recognise that this is actually an update and that data with the same key already exist in this section.

The second problem is probably related to the first one, but now I'm not sure.

Here's an interactive bl.ocks.org: https://bl.ocks.org/mattleonowicz/fd975a6d914f90c9934464df57e498c9

Same code below:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="app" /> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const data1 = [
  {
    category: {
      id: 1
    },
    checkins: [
      {
        lat: 1,
        lon: 1
      },
      {
        lat: 2,
        lon: 2
      }
      // ... more objects like this would normally be here
    ]
  }
  // ... more objects like this would normally be here
];
const data2 = [
  {
    category: {
      id: 1
    },
    checkins: [
      {
        lat: 3,
        lon: 3
      },
      {
        lat: 4,
        lon: 4
      }
      // ... more objects like this would normally be here
    ]
  }
  // ... more objects like this would normally be here
];

update(data1);
setTimeout(() => update(data2), 2000);
setTimeout(() => update(data1), 4000);

function update(data) {
  const categoriesData = d3.select('#app')
    .selectAll('section')
    .data(data, d => d.category.id);

  // CATEGORIES EXIT
  categoriesData.exit()
    .remove();

  // CATEGORIES UPDATE + ENTER - bind all categories with their checkins
  const checkinsData = categoriesData.enter()
    .append('section')
    .merge(categoriesData)
    .selectAll('section')
    .data(d => d.checkins, d => `${d.lon},${d.lat}`);

  // CHECKINS UPDATE : nothing, because checkins will only come and go

  // CHECKINS EXIT
  checkinsData.exit()
    .remove();

  // CHECKINS ENTER
  checkinsData.enter()
    .append('div')
    .html(d => `${d.lon},${d.lat}`);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
  // CATEGORIES UPDATE + ENTER - bind all categories with their checkins
  const checkinsData = categoriesData.enter()
    .append('section')
    .merge(categoriesData)
->  .selectAll('section')
    .data(d => d.checkins, d => `${d.lon},${d.lat}`);
```

You wanted to write `.selectAll('div')` in the second selection.

Comment: Yes, that is the case actually. I also discovered that even if I would have divs on both levels then I would need to add class to the divs higher in hierarchy so that the first selection would look like `const categoriesData = d3.select('#app').selectAll('div.category').data(data, d => d.category.id);` and the update/enter section would look like `const checkinsData = categoriesData.enter().append('div').attr('class', 'category') ...` in order for it to work again. Thank you @Yaroslav